# How to implement a command to delete an item from my database in xamarinforms mvvm style

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently i have a clicked function that delete an items :

```
async void DeleteButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ImageButton button = sender as ImageButton;
    var agenda = button.BindingContext as Agenda;

    await App.Database.DeleteAgendaAsync(agenda);
    
    await Navigation.PopAsync();

}
```

I want to implement this MVVM style with a command, the basic of my app is that i have an AgendaPage that loads items in a collection view, right now i want to be able to call the command on this icon and so it delete the item.

Thanks for your help.

**Currently in my PageViewModel i only have this**
I have to pass the current agenda to the DeleteAgendaAsync() method but it's unclear to me where to get it.

```
public Command DeleteAgendaCommand { get; set; }

public AgendaPageViewModel()
{
    DeleteAgendaCommand = new Command(async () => await DeleteAgenda());
}
async Task DeleteAgenda()
{

    await App.Database.DeleteAgendaAsync();

}
```

**AgendaDatabase.cs in the Database folder**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using SQLite;
using Calculette.Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Calculette.ViewModel;

namespace Calculette.Database
{

    

    public class AgendaDatabase
    {
        readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

        public AgendaDatabase(string dbPath)
        {
           
            database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            database.CreateTableAsync<Agenda>().Wait();
        


        }

        // Get all agenda
        public Task<List<Agenda>> GetAgendasAsync()
        {

            return database.Table<Agenda>().ToListAsync();
        }

        // Get specific agenda
        public Task<Agenda> GetAgendaAsync(int id)
        {
            return database.Table<Agenda>()
                            .Where(i => i.ID == id)
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        // Insert new agenda (save)
        public Task<int> SaveAgendaAsync(Agenda agenda)
        {
            if (agenda.ID != 0)
            {
                return database.UpdateAsync(agenda);
            }
            else
            {
                return database.InsertAsync(agenda);
            }
        }
        
        //Delete specific agenda
        public Task<int> DeleteAgendaAsync(Agenda agenda)
        {
            return database.DeleteAsync(agenda);
        }
        public Task<int> AddAgendaAsync(Agenda agenda)
        {
            return database.InsertAsync(agenda);
        }
    }
}
```

**Agenda.cs in the Models folder**

```
[Table("Agenda")]
public class Agenda
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

**This is the NewFormViewModel.cs which is used to create new agenda items to the collectionview, it feels like i would need to access all the items added there, but im unsure on how to do that for the DeleteCommand**

```
using Calculette.Database;
using Calculette.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Calculette.ViewModel
{
    class NewFormViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        public Command AgendaSaveFormCommand { get; set; }


        public NewFormViewModel()
        {
            // Initialise la valeur du DatePicker a celle d'aujourd'hui
            this.Date = DateTime.Now;

            // Commande pour la sauvegarde sur la page NewFormPage ( voir SaveForm() plus bas)
            AgendaSaveFormCommand = new Command(async () => await SaveForm(), () => !IsBusy);
            
        }

        // Création des propriétés d'un agenda

        private string topic;
        public string Topic
        {
            get => topic;
            set
            {
                topic = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string duration;
        public string Duration
        {
            get => duration;
            set
            {
                duration = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private DateTime date;
        public DateTime Date
        {
            get => date;
            set
            {
                date = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        bool isBusy = false;
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return isBusy; }
            set
            {
                isBusy = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged();

                AgendaSaveFormCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
            }
        }

        public int ID { get; }


        // Methode qui enregistre un agenda et l'ajoute a la collection d'agenda de AgendaPage
        async Task SaveForm()
        {
            
         IsBusy = true;
         await Task.Delay(4000);

            
           IsBusy = false;
           // Agenda agenda = new Agenda();
            //ObservableCollection<Agenda> agenda = new ObservableCollection<Agenda>();
            Agenda agenda = new Agenda();

            agenda.Topic = Topic;
            agenda.Date = Date;
            agenda.Duration = Duration;
            await App.Database.SaveAgendaAsync(agenda);

            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Save", "La tâche a été enregistrée", "OK");
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
    }
```

**AgendaPage.xaml**

```
 <CollectionView Grid.Row="2" Margin="25" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        SelectionMode="Single"  x:Name="AgendaCollection" ItemsSource="{Binding Agendas}"> <!--ItemsSource="{Binding AngedaCollection}" -->
                    <CollectionView.Header>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="220">
                            <Label Text="Agenda" TextColor="Black" FontSize="18"/>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                
                            
                                <ImageButton Source="iconplus.png"  HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Clicked="GoToNewFormPage"></ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton Source="iconmoins.png"  HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Clicked="DeleteButtonClicked"></ImageButton>
                            </StackLayout>


                        </StackLayout>
                        
                        

                    </CollectionView.Header>

                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="20"/>
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            
                                <pv:PancakeView HasShadow="True" BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand " 
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <BoxView BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}" WidthRequest="3" HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                    <Expander Grid.Column="1" >
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3.5*"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:dd}'}" TextColor="#008A00" FontSize="27" 
                                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:MMMM}'}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="10" 
                                                   HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,-10,0,0" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                    <ImageButton Source="iconplus.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Clicked="GoToFormPage"></ImageButton>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                                <BoxView Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="#F2F4F8" WidthRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                                <StackLayout x:Name="topicLayout" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="20">
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Topic}" TextColor="#008A00" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Duration}" TextColor="#2F3246" FontSize="12" Margin="0,-10,0,0"/>
                                                    <ImageButton Source="iconmoins.png"  HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference AgendaCollection}, Path=AgendaPageViewModel.DeleteAgendaCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></ImageButton>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="3.5*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <BoxView Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="#F2F4F8" WidthRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                            <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Spacing="10">
                                                <Label Text="Tâches" TextColor="Black" FontSize="15" Margin="20,0"/>
                                                <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Speakers}" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="20,0,0,20">
                                                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <Label TextColor="#2F3246" FontSize="12">
                                                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                                                    <FormattedString>
                                                                        <FormattedString.Spans>
                                                                            <Span Text="{Binding Time}"/>
                                                                            <Span Text=" - "/>
                                                                            <Span Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                                        </FormattedString.Spans>
                                                                    </FormattedString>
                                                                </Label.FormattedText>
                                                            </Label>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                        
                                                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                    
                                                </StackLayout>

                                                
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Expander>
                                </Grid>
                            </pv:PancakeView>
                            
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
```

Comment: i am assuming your PageViewModel is for all agendas and not just one. In this case you could use the property SelectedItem or SelectedItems of the CollectionView and bind that to a property in your viewModel. Than you can use this each time delete is called to pass it on to your DeleteAgendaAsync function

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, what im not sure is what to pass as paramater to my await App.Database.DeleteAgendaAsync( PARAMETER ); method,  in PageViewModel. It needs the current clicked   agenda but im confuse on how to initiate it in this page

Comment: sure i will write a more detailed answer give me a few minutes. By the way do you use one delete button for each Agenda or you select an Agenda and use a single delete button for all?

Comment: i have a delete button for each Agenda created ! Thanks :) tell me if you need me to put more detail

Comment: Ok thanks, i added both ways, maybe someone will need it and they are very similar anyway. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Hi, i tried the answer #2 and nothing happen when i click my icon. I added my xaml in the original post, you can see where is the delete icon ( moinsicon.png), i added the way you binded there. Maybe the problem is that i am using an expander so when i click on the item, it doesn't get the selected item, it just expand my collection. In DeleteButtonClicked function that you can see at the start of the post, i had this problem fixed with     ImageButton button = sender as ImageButton;
    var agenda = button.BindingContext as Agenda;Is there a way to do that here in the Viewmodel?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216678/discussion-between-hannes-and-codejourney).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure where you have your delete button, so here are two possible ways of doing this:

#### 1) You select an Agenda from the CollectionView and then use one Button to delete this agenda:

Add the SelectedItem as a Property to the ViewModel like that:

```
ObservableCollection<Agenda> agendas = new ObservableCollection<Agenda>();

public ObservableCollection<Agenda> Agendas { get => agendas; set => agendas = value; }

public Agenda SelectedItem { get; set; }
public Command Delete { get; set; }

public ViewModel()
{
    Agendas.Add(new Agenda() { Name = "test" });
    Agendas.Add(new Agenda() { Name = "test2" });
    Agendas.Add(new Agenda() { Name = "test3" });
    Delete = new Command(new Action<object>((obj) =>
    {
        DeleteAsync(SelectedItem);
    }));
}

private void DeleteAsync(Agenda selectedItem)
{
    //delete Agenda here
}
```

To use this simply bind the SelectedItem property of the CollectionView to your ViewModel:

```
 <StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.BindingContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </StackLayout.BindingContext>

    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Agendas}" 
                    SelectionMode="Single" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="120" Margin="12"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
    <Button Text="Delete" Command="{Binding Delete}" />

</StackLayout>
```

---

#### 2) You have a button to delete an Agenda for each Agenda:

You can setup your ViewModel similar to this:

```
ObservableCollection<Agenda> agendas = new ObservableCollection<Agenda>();     
public ObservableCollection<Agenda> Agendas { get => agendas; set => agendas = value; }

public Command Delete { get; set; }

public ViewModel()
{
    Delete = new Command(new Action<object>((obj) =>
    {
        DeleteAsync((Agenda) obj);
    }));
}

private void DeleteAsync(Agenda selectedItem)
{
    //delete Agenda here
}
```

Then you can set this up in xaml like this:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.BindingContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </StackLayout.BindingContext>

    <CollectionView x:Name="AgendaCollection"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Agendas}" >
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Topic}" FontSize="120" Margin="12"/>
                        <Button Text="Delete" 
                                Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference AgendaCollection}, Path=BindingContext.Delete}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

</StackLayout>
```

Note you can directly Bind to a Command, you dont have to use ButtonClicked and than pass it on.

In this case you have to change the Binding Source to the CollectionView (give that a x:Name and Bind to that) because the Binding Context inside the DataTemplate will be set to the Children of the ItemSource (the individual Agendas). That way the command is automatically executed without the Clicked event.

To pass on the Agenda on which delete was clicked to the Command you can set the CommandParameter. Here it Binds to itself (As i said CollectionView will set the DataContext of its elements to the corresponding individual element.)